# Google Analytics Embed API authentication

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm looking at getting some stats out of Google Analytics using the Embed API to display on our site using javascript.

My question is:

Is it possible to display the stats without the user authenticating? I.e. I would like to make some traffic statistics available to anonymous users.

Thanks,
Chris.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is definitely possible, but you'll have to get the access token yourself (server side, using whatever [OAuth 2.0 flow](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2) you want).

Once you have a valid access token, you can pass it to the `gapi.analytics.auth` component and use the Embed API as normal.

Here's some documentation on that:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/component-reference#auth

#### UPDATE: (07/27/2015)

A demo of [server-side authorization with the Embed API](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/server-side-authorization/) is now featured on the [Google Analytics Demos & Tools site](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com). You should look there to see a working example.

Comment: Does this give the user access to Google Analytics outside the scope of what I display with Embed API? (i.e. can the user manipulate the page to display whatever they want from analytics?)

Comment: The key point here is that **somebody** is always authorizing the access. If you don't want your site's users to have to authorize then **you** will have to authorize on their behalf (usually on the back-end), and whatever visibility/control you give them, they're doing those actions in your name. So it's really up to you how much access you want to grant.

Comment: @Jammer it's back up. I think it was just a temporary issue.