# How to by pass authentication in google analytics script?

Tags: google-api, google-analytics-api

I would like to display a Google Analytics report in my web application. So far I have successfully Authenticated a user through OAuth with server side and I have successfully stored AccessToken and UserProfileId in my database Table.

Now I want to display Chart like Below:

[image]

Here is the script which I have taken from the source to display above chart: [Embeded API demo](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/basic-dashboard/)

Script:

```
gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
    container: 'embed-api-auth-container',
    clientid: 'REPLACE WITH YOUR CLIENT ID', // i dont want to authenticate here as i have already done authentication.instead use access token to by pass this
                                               authentication
  });
```

So is it possible to not authenticate user with this script and still display google analytics chart for login user??

I have search on internet and I found below link somewhat useful in which Philip Walton answer is saying that it is possible:  [Google Analytics Embed API authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26590159/google-analytics-embed-api-authentication)

So if anybody have done this then please do provide any solution.

Comment: I fail to see how this is not a duplicate of the question you linked to - the documentation linked by Philip Walton has actually a complete example for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this option [Embed API - Component Reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/component-reference#data-options)  from this link which solved my issue:

I just needed to set the access_token:

```
gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
     serverAuth: {
        access_token: 'XXXXXX'
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

> try this using JavaScript sdk

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Embed API Demo</title>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Step 1: Create the containing elements. -->

<section id="auth-button"></section>
<section id="view-selector"></section>
<section id="timeline"></section>
<hr/>
<section id="chart-1-container"></section>




<!-- Step 2: Load the library. -->

<script>
(function(w,d,s,g,js,fjs){
  g=w.gapi||(w.gapi={});g.analytics={q:[],ready:function(cb){this.q.push(cb)}};
  js=d.createElement(s);fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  js.src='https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);js.onload=function(){g.load('analytics')};
}(window,document,'script'));
</script>

<script>
gapi.analytics.ready(function() {

  // Step 3: Authorize the user.

  var CLIENT_ID = 'xxxxxxxxxxx-xxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com';

  //gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
  //  container: 'auth-button',
  //  clientid: CLIENT_ID,
  //});

   gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
    'serverAuth': {
      'access_token': 'xx.xxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxx'
    }
  });

  // Step 4: Create the view selector.

  var viewSelector = new gapi.analytics.ViewSelector({
    container: 'view-selector'
  });

  // Step 5: Create the timeline chart.

  var timeline = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
    reportType: 'ga',
    query: {
      'dimensions': 'ga:date',
      'metrics': 'ga:users',
      'start-date': '30daysAgo',
      'end-date': 'yesterday',
    },
    chart: {
      type: 'LINE',
      container: 'timeline'
    }
  });

  var dataChart1 = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
    query: {
      'ids': 'ga:xxxxxxxx', // <-- Replace with the ids value for your view.
      'start-date': '30daysAgo',
      'end-date': 'yesterday',
      'metrics': 'ga:sessions,ga:users',
      'dimensions': 'ga:date'
    },
    chart: {
      'container': 'chart-1-container',
      'type': 'LINE',
      'options': {
        'width': '100%'
      }
    }
  });
  dataChart1.execute();

  // Step 6: Hook up the components to work together.

  gapi.analytics.auth.on('success', function(response) {
    viewSelector.execute();
  });

  viewSelector.on('change', function(ids) {
    var newIds = {
      query: {
        ids: ids
      }
    }
    timeline.set(newIds).execute();
  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```