# Google Analytics Embed API

Tags: google-analytics-api

I am working on embedding of our google analytics dashboard in our web portal using its API, after walking through this example, [Embed API - Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/devguide)

I am facing a problem; that when I logged in to google analytics account and run this example, it is fetching the results, but when there is no logged in session, it returns

> Object { errors=[1](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/devguide),  code=403,  message="User does not have any
>   Google Analytics account."}

retrieved from browsers developer tools... I have added the service account email address to Analytics Admin Console as well. please suggest the solution

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Analytics Embed API authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26590159/google-analytics-embed-api-authentication)

Comment: not 100% the same @EikePierstorff hes got an error message which is diffrent

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question - I assumed the OP wanted data from the embed API without logging in with his own credentials (in which case the other answer seems to apply, even if the question is different).

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a session logged in with access to the account.

Check the Google Account you are logging in with it needs to be one that has access to the Google Analytics account that you want to check.   The Google account you are authenticating with currently doesn't have access to any Google Analytics Accounts.

Service account wont work with embedded API you need to use Oauth2.

Comment: Thanks, But Its not mentioned anywhere in said Guides of Google, Then how can we utilized Analytics Embed API with OAuth2 in particular using ASP.NET, is there any example work for this... 
and what about this developers.google.com/oauthplayground and its implementation –

Comment: The embedded API isn't C# its JavaScript that's what makes it so nice to use.   You could technically develop something from the ground up using Google graphics and charts and the Google .NET client library with the Google API.  Sounds like an interesting project really

Comment: Yes it is JS based, we need to develop the dashboard of our own analytics in our web application, this can be in JS or C#, please advise some proper route for this along with some code example if feasible, thanks in advance.